# How to select color file based on filetype?

Tags: vim

I want to source a color file based on the filetype python. How can I do that in .vimrc?

Comment: Do you mean that you want syntax highlighting for files associated with Python?

Comment: Yes. I just noticed that there is a variable set, b:current_syntax which is set to python. I am not able to read this in .vimrc file :( This probably can solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### EDIT:

ZyX makes a valid point that the use of `Buf*` events will not ensure that the colorscheme is set correctly for python files where the filetype is set after the file is loaded (e.g., python files without the `.py` extension or if you begin writing a script in a new buffer and manually set `filetype=python`). As per ZyX's suggestion in the comments below, here's one that uses the `FileType` event.

```
autocmd FileType * if &filetype == 'python' | colorscheme jellybeans | else | colorscheme wombat256 | endif
```

---

My previous answer is here below:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufEnter,BufRead * if &filetype == 'python' | colorscheme jellybeans | else | colorscheme wombat256 | endif
```

The earlier command changed the colorscheme once you entered a python file and it remained so for the rest of the session. This one lets you have one type of colorscheme for python files and another type for the others.

Comment: This is very good, thanks! Yesterday I tried another one which also works: au BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.py so $VIMRUNTIME\colors\slate.vim, and your latter one is more powerful.

Comment: @Ethan Collins, @yoda There is `FileType` event for this case.

Comment: @ZyX: I tried that first, but just `au FileType python blah` changed the settings once I moved into a python file and remained that way for all subsequent (non py) files. I wasn't sure how to add a conditional here... Could you please explain how?

Comment: @yoda colorscheme settings are not local, so you should just replace `BufNewFile,BufEnter,BufRead` with `Filetype` and let `* if...` part of your answer be the same. And you should not define first autocommand at all: it is already defined by runtime files distributed with vim.

Comment: @yoda The only reason why `FileType` should be used here is that it provides ability to edit python files with favourite colorscheme if you set filetype after file is loaded. For example, if filetype is set with modeline and file does not end with `.py` for some reason, your BufRead command will fire before filetype is set.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got syntax highlighting for cuda (*.cu and *.cuh) on my machine.  Might be helpful for you (I modified it to fit python):

Download a python.vim file from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) and put it somewhere (I put it in ~/)

Add this to your .vimrc

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set filetype=py
au! Syntax py source ~/python.vim
```

Comment: Thanks. I achieve the first statement with the setting 'filetype on'. Thanks for the sourcing command.